# Multiple node selector with kubectl run

Tags: kubernetes

I am using a command for pod creation plus node selection

```
kubectl run newpod --image image1 --command run over --overrides='{ "apiVersion": "v1", "spec": { "template": { "spec": { "nodeSelector": { "kubernetes.io/hostname": "one-worker-node" } } } } }'
```

the problem is it that it runs on one worker node named "one-worker-node". I could not make it run for two or more worker nodes. like

```
kubectl run newpod --image image1 --command run over --overrides='{ "apiVersion": "v1", "spec": { "template": { "spec": { "nodeSelector": { "kubernetes.io/hostname": "one-worker-node" : "second-worker-node"} } } } }'
```

Comment: Generally you'd use a Kubernetes Deployment object with `kubectl apply`, and you wouldn't really worry about what specific nodes your Pods get placed on.  Is there a larger problem you're trying to work through that you need to use `kubectl run` or that you're trying to override Kubernetes's default placement algorithm?

Comment: @DavidMaze I just need to run pod on two specific nodes. because I want to use a specific service on two nodes. I do not want to involve the third one. Could you help me to modify the command?

Comment: that JSON doesn't look right to me.

Comment: Could you help me to create the right one for multiple node selectors @suren?

Comment: @Realsuper I added an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do it with `nodeSelector`, because you would need to pass two key-values, with the same key. Something like this:

```
kubectl run newpod --image image1 --overrides='{ "apiVersion": "v1", "spec": { "nodeSelector": { "kubernetes.io/hostname": "one-worker-node", "kubernetes.io/hostname": "second-worker-node" } } }'
```

Which is equivalent to this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    run: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/hostname: one-worker-node
    kubernetes.io/hostname: second-worker-node
```

If you'd deploy this pod, only the last label will take effect, as the first label will be overritten in the Pod yaml.

So, you would use `nodeAffinity`. This one should work from the command line:

```
kubectl run newpod --image image1 --overrides='{ "spec": { "affinity": { "nodeAffinity": { "requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution": { "nodeSelectorTerms": [{ "matchExpressions": [{ "key": "kubernetes.io/hostname",  "operator": "In", "values": [ "one-worker-node", "second-worker-node" ]} ]} ]} } } } }'
```

Which is equivalent to this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: newpod
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
            operator: In
            values:
            - one-worker-node
            - second-worker-node
  containers:
  - name: image1
    image: image1
```

You can add all your candidates to the `values`. Also you might want to make it a preference with `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution`, or have both; a preference and a requirement.

**PoC**

```
root@master-1-v1-20:~# kubectl get no
NAME             STATUS   ROLES      AGE   VERSION
master-1-v1-20   Ready    master     43d   v1.20.2
worker-1-v1-20   Ready    worker-1   42d   v1.20.2
worker-2-v1-20   Ready    worker-2   42d   v1.20.2
root@master-1-v1-20:~# grep affinity -A8 affinity.yaml 
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
            operator: In
            values:
            - worker-1-v1-20 
root@master-1-v1-20:~# kubectl create -f affinity.yaml 
pod/newpod created
root@master-1-v1-20:~# kubectl get po newpod -owide
NAME     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP                NODE             NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
newpod   1/1     Running   0          18s   192.168.127.102   worker-1-v1-20   <none>           <none>
```

I change the name to `newpod-2` and configure it to run on the second node:

```
root@master-1-v1-20:~# vim affinity.yaml 
root@master-1-v1-20:~# grep affinity -A8 affinity.yaml 
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
            operator: In
            values:
            - worker-2-v1-20 
root@master-1-v1-20:~# kubectl create -f affinity.yaml 
pod/newpod-2 created
root@master-1-v1-20:~# kubectl get po newpod newpod-2 -owide
NAME       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP                NODE             NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
newpod     1/1     Running   0          4m26s   192.168.127.102   worker-1-v1-20   <none>           <none>
newpod-2   1/1     Running   0          3m25s   192.168.118.172   worker-2-v1-20   <none>           <none>
```

Comment: I have tried but it pod still shows on the last node like   I have two nodes                                                   
 2nd-workernode   Ready    <none>                 9d     v1.20.4   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=2nd-workernode,kubernetes.io/os=linux
3rd-workernode   Ready    <none>                 9d     v1.20.4   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=3rd-workernode,kubernetes.io/os=linux

Comment: nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
            operator: In
            values:
            - 2nd-workernode
            - 3rd-workernode

Comment: and result is still                                      sudo kubectl get nodes -o wide newpod8      1/1     Running            0          2d      10.38.0.7    3rd-workernode   <none>           <none>

Comment: it still only run on 3rd-worker node and not on 2nd worker node @suren

Comment: @Realsuper has to work. I added a PoC to my answer, and it just worked. I only have two nodes tho.